# Good equipments to measure current consumption for IoT devices

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, multimeter, device, test-equipment

I was asked to bought some equipment to measure the current consumption for the IoT devices. The company is a startup and has a limited budget for this (let's say less than 5k$).

I'm looking for an instrument that can:

- Capture the sleep current (around a few uA)
- Capture the active current (around a few mA)
- Capture the transmiting current (around a few hundred mA)
- Can store the recorded samples in file (about 100 millions samples or more). Testing time can last for 1-2 days to estimate the battery life.
- Sample rate >= 1 KSamples/s

Would you please suggest me some names (DMM or oscilloscope)? Do I need a current probe for this purpose?

Comment: Equipment to measure high sample rate, high resolution, with large dynamic range can get pricey. Try performing separate measurements: measure only the uA current segments, then measure only the mA segments. After measuring each range with high resolution, use information from each. This should be suitable if what you are measuring is predictable. A bench PSU and oscilloscope with varying sense resistors will do just fine.

Comment: Also, I'm unsure of the exact policy on asking for product recommendations of *test equipment*, but it may be frowned upon by some here.

Comment: insufficient specs:   #channels, dynamic range of 1e5 with what resolution and accuracy?  that implies>6 or 7 digits. maybe you could use an I2C coulomb counter IC

Comment: Rigol DS1000Z has a promotion with 24Ms memory but not 100Ms, but you have to program the scale changes in time and then dump intervals of captures

Comment: But if you want accuracy, go for Keithley 34461A DMM >50ks/s or 6 1/2 digits

Comment: Why not use a diode-connected BJT and a power supply with Kelvin-sense leads? Would give the wide dynamic range. Sensitivity would be about a 1% change in voltage for a 20% change in current at the low end to a 1% change in voltage for a 30% change in current at the high end. Put BJT in well-stirred ice-water bath. Use very cheap ADC. Ice water is cheap, too.

Comment: I don't think I have every used Kelvin leads for anything less than 1 Amp but I like the ice water thermal stabilizing diode but current changes almost 6 decades

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I know. I figured at least 5 orders. The diode-connected BJT can do okay over that range, if you can get one whose region II spans the desired range. (This is the "normal" region that is neither too low and pestered by surface channel problems nor too high and challenged other ways.) The Kelvin leads I didn't explain. But the DUT has a power supply to it and the BJT would have to be in series with the main supply. I'd place the Kelvin leads on the DUT and place the diode in series with the OUT of the supply. This regulates the DUT but current goes through BJT, too.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 See: [proposed concept](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j0LbI.png)

Comment: Thank you @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 for your suggestions. I found 34465A DMM from Keysight Techonology to be fit with the requirements. Before suggesting this to my manager, may I ask if (1) you have any oscilloscope suggestion (DS1000Z could not store data into USB. Since we want to estimate the current consumption for 1-2 days. Internal memory won't be sufficient); (2) for oscilloscope, I need to use a current probe or a shunt resistor, do I? (3) I feel like 34465A is one of the cheepest for the same specs. Am I correct (well, I would like the cheapest one)?

Comment: Better to talk to local Reps and get demo units

Comment: DC current probes are expensive. 50mV shunt is cheap use Keithley

Comment: http://www.saelig.com/MFR00062/PSBE100015.htm

Comment: This link: https://iot.eetimes.com/new-development-tool-that-simplifies-measurement-and-analysis-of-energy-consumption-of-iot-devices-and-apps/ Above link has what you need

Comment: You don't need a scope for this, you want a higher resolution *slower* ADC.  While you care about seeing changes over time, what you are looking at is ultimately an *average* impact, and perhaps correlation of power consumption with operations like a packet transmission, ie things that likely happen over several milliseconds or more, so as long as you have enough capacitance in the power system that your sampling rate substantially exceeds the analog bandwidth, you can use a merely moderate speed ADC.

Answer (score 1):

I think a keithley SMU or an equivalent would be your best bet. It is within your budget and does exactly what you need.

https://www.tek.com/keithley-source-measure-units/keithley-smu-2400-series-sourcemeter

there is also a battery simulator, but I think it lacks some of the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but a few pointers:

- Nordic Power Profiler kit:  https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-Tools/Development-Kits/Power-Profiler-Kit Works great with Nordic dev boards, easily usable for any other microamps to milliamps range circuit.  Specs are 77kHz, 0.2uA resolution. Can record the millisecond long high current spikes when the nRF51 radio is on.
- EEVBlog uCurrent: http://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent Solves the problem of voltage drop through a sense resistor quite nicely.  Good analog bandwidth at 300kHz (better than Nordic), converts uA/nA current to mV voltage (so can measure much lower current than Nordic), but you still need a DSO or fast data logger to record the output.  uCurrent+Saleae Logic is a good combo for very long recordings (really, just limited by your hard drive/SSD).  Hours to days at 100ksps works.

I've used both of the above for fairly complex projects.  Never had access to the big rigs (Keysight, HP etc) so I can't compare.  All of the above together is well under $1k.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I am the designer for ZS-2102-A.

A power profiler is most suited for this application. There is one from qoitech which retails on Digikey and other distributors.

Another good one is "ZS-2102-A" from ZSCircuits. It is available for sale at www.anglercircuits.com. This tool can measure from few uA to 1A with 2us response time. It can record practically unlimited record time. Available for $699 with added discounts and free shipping.

Comment: Do you have an affiliation with anglercircuits?

Comment: Disclaimer : I am the designer for the ZS-2102-A and own the company ZSCircuits

Comment: You need to, at least, add that to your user profile and should state it in your post (as you have done). Otherwise your posts will be deleted as spam. If you do it in your profile you can add a link there.